# Confusion about the different efficiency between emplacement and insertion for containers not allowing duplicates

Tags: c++, c++11, insert, emplace, effective-c++

In Item 41 from *Effective Modern C++*, the following is one of the situations that give a chance for emplacement functions to be more performant than the insertion conterparts:

> The container is unlikely to reject the new value as a duplicate

the reason being that, given *the arguments to the constructor* of the oject whose insertion in the container is attempted, the emplace function will have to construct that object to asses whether it is already present in the container, in which case the construction has been a waste, followed by the unavoidable waste of the desctruction too.

I have already some doubts here. If I was to use the insertion function to avoid this scenario, then I would be constructing the object myself (probably a temporary, passing to its construtor the arguments that I'd pass to the emplacement function), and passing it to the insertion function, and then that temporary, if an equal value was in the container already, would got destroyed.

So I don't see a difference.

Furthermore, the author adds that

> Such nodes are created for emplacement functions more often than for insertion functions.

Why in the world should which function I use to insert an object in a container influece if that object is already in the container?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if and how this applies to the unordered containers. But a `std::set` is normally internally represented by a binary tree (often a red-black tree). You can assume that the nodes look somewhat like this:

```
struct Node {
    Node* parent, left_child, right_child;
    value_type value;
}
```

Now let's see what happens when emplacing and inserting:

- `emplace(args...)`: Now, we need a `value_type`-object to be able to do the comparison. But we will not create a temporary that we will later move (`std::set` does not require `value_type` to be either moveable or copyable!). We will directly create a `Node a` on the heap and construct `value` inplace from `args`. After that we check if `value` is already in the set. If so, we delete `a` and are done. Otherwise we adjust the `Node*` of `a` to take it into the set.
- `insert(val)`: Here, we already have an object (that may be a temporary). So we find out if it is already in the set. If so, nothing happens and we are done. If it is not in the set, we now allocate a `Node` and copy/move val into that `Node` and set the `Node*` to take it into the set.

Now let's analyze the different szenarios.

- `emplace(args...)`: It does not matter if the `value_type` object constructed from `args...` is already in the map. We will always allocate one `Node` and use the `value_type(args...)` constructor once. No moves, no copies. If the object is already present, we will `delete` a `Node` thereby calling the destructor of `value_type`.
- `insert(val)`: If `val` is already present, we make no constructions at all in `insert`. If not, we allocate one `Node` and copy/move `val` into it. If you construct `val` from `args...` while passing it to `insert` (i.e. call `insert(value_type(args...))`), then we of course have another `value_type(args...)` and also a call to the destructor of this temporary.

So, `emplace` will always have an allocation of `Node`, regardless of the value being present or not. `insert(value_type(args...))` will no have that if the value was present, but it will have an extra move, if the value was not present.

So if your container will likely reject the object, you will have needless heap allocations for the `Node`. This can be more costly than the extra move from `insert`. Also, you will see that it is never reasonable to `emplace` an already existing object, since that will only add `Node`-allocations<sup>1</sup> if it fails and has no bonus.

---

1: One could have another overload of `emplace(value_type)` to not do that. I am not sure if the standard libraries do that.